# How to get correct height and width of Fabric.js object after modifying

Tags: fabricjs

After drawing an object and modifying the object with the mouse, the  coordinates(Object.width and Object.height) remain the same as the originally drawn object.

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function load() {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    fill: 'yellow',
  });

  function objectAddedListener(ev) {
    let target = ev.target;
    console.log('left', target.left, 'top', target.top, 'width', target.width, 'height', target.height);
  }

  function objectMovedListener(ev) {
    let target = ev.target;
    console.log('left', target.left, 'top', target.top, 'width', target.width, 'height', target.height);
  }

  canvas.on('object:added', objectAddedListener);
  canvas.on('object:modified', objectMovedListener);

  canvas.add(rect);

}

load();

button.addEventListener('click', load);
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/robhicks/pen/rpzGYE)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
width = target.width * target.scaleX, 
height = target.height * target.scaleY
```

As we are scalling, so you need to multiply the scaleX and scaleY value to width and height respectively. Here is updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/ypoGJb)

Answer (score 2):

Currently You can use:

```
this.yourObject.getScaledWidth();
this.yourObject.getScaledHeight();
```

Which returns the same result.